# Where can I learn more about this creepy diary?

Tags: ghost

[image]

I saw this on 9 gag, etc. Is this fantasy or some kid actually make this up? Where can I found more info about this.

Comment: http://www.scaryforkids.com/diary-of-a-girl/

Comment: Well, it's on the Internet, so it *must* be true.

Comment: Did somebody write that as a fiction or is it really a diary of a little girl?

Comment: @JohnP : i think you can make that an answer... Maybe also add the link to the originals at deviantArt : http://ocularfracture.deviantart.com/gallery/39994101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was basically blog fiction, by a user named OcularFracture. Here are a couple of links to it:

[Scary for kids website](http://www.scaryforkids.com/diary-of-a-girl/)

[Original on deviant art (Story of Lisa)](http://ocularfracture.deviantart.com/gallery/39994101)